# MVC URL routing to target specific urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am working on a website and I would like to create some SEO friendly Urls.
So far I have managed to do the following:

*wwww.mywebsite.com/laptops/brand*

*wwww.mywebsite.com/laptops/brand/model.*

This was all achieved by adding the necessary routes in the RouteConfig.

Now i am facing an issued, which i am asking for some help.
If you navigate to wwww.mywebsite.com/laptops/brand/model and then submit my search form for another search, the url structure will look like this:

**wwww.mywebsite.com/laptops/brand/model?Brand=NewSelectedBrand?Model=NewSelectedModel...**

What should i do in order to have the url structure for the new search follow the same pattern -> mywebsite.com/laptops/NewSelelectedBrand/NewSelectedModel ?

As requested: 
This is the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Laptops", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "", id = "searchForm" }))
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedBrand)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedModel)                    
}
```

In my route config i have the following in this order:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"LaptopListings-BrandModel",
"search/laptop-listings/{SelectedBrand}/{SelectedModel}",
new
{
    controller = "Search",
    action = "LaptopListings",
    SelectedBrand = UrlParameter.Optional,
    SelectedModel = UrlParameter.Optional
});

routes.MapRoute(
"LaptopListings-Brand",
"search/laptop-listings/{SelectedBrand}",
 new
 {
     controller = "Search",
     action = "LaptopListings",
    SelectedBrand = UrlParameter.Optional
 });
routes.MapRoute(
"LaptopListings",
"search/laptop-listings",
new
{
     controller = "Search",
     action = "LaptopListings"
 });
```

Comment: You need to show your code. Best guess is you have a form with `FormMethod.Get`?

Comment: I have updated my question @StephenMuecke, is there anything else i can provide to better explain the scenario ?

Comment: I have marked it as a dupe because it explains the behavior, but there other other things not making sense with your view. Only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`. And your form only has hidden inputs so how are you doing a search?

Comment: Those hidden fields are just placeholders which i update when the user changes selections. I have read your explanations on the other question and i understand the behavior now. So only javascript can help me with these scenarios ? And thanks for also mentioning `UrlParameter.Optional`, i was not aware of this !